# Test by random data

Tags: c++, testing, random

I am doing my school homework on university - program which takes 2 binary numbers and write their sum. My university uses a special software for testing homeworks and one of tests is "Test by random data" which my program cant pass, can someone give me some tips where the problem can be? Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int B2D(string number)
{
    int result = 0, pow = 1;
    for ( int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i, pow <<= 1 )
        result += (number[i] - '0') * pow;

    return result;
}
string D2B(int number)
{
    if ( number == 0 ) return "0";
    if ( number == 1 ) return "1";

    if ( number % 2 == 0 )
        return D2B(number / 2) + "0";
    else
        return D2B(number / 2) + "1";
}
int main()
{
    string input_number;
    string input_number2;
    cout << "Write 2 binary numbers" << endl;
    if(!(cin >> input_number >> input_number2))
    {
        cout << "Wrong entry." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<input_number.size();i++){
        if((input_number[i] != '1') && (input_number[i] != '0'))
        {
            cout << "Wrong entry." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<input_number2.size();i++){
        if((input_number2[i] != '1') && (input_number2[i] != '0'))
        {
            cout << "Wrong entry."<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    int result = B2D(input_number);
    int result2 = B2D(input_number2);
    int result3 = result + result2;
    string result4 = D2B(result3);
    cout << "Result: " << result4 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what "can't pass" means? What's "random data?" What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried doing that test yourself and stepping through the debugger?

Comment: Well i actually dont know what it is, thats the problem, only thing i know is that it test the program with "Random data". Expected behaviour is that if you write two binary numbers, it prints their sum, if you write anything else then 1 or 0, it prints "Wrong entry". Program is working well, when i test it with normal binnary numbers and when i do smthing like "10020 ea56f" aka input with wrong chars (other than 0 and 1), it prints "Wrong entry", i rly dont know where the problem is.

Comment: @user1751550 Is the period '.' after "Wrong entry" supposed to be part of the output? The output-checking script might be quite pedantic for things like that.

Comment: test with random data means they generate the input data using some random number generator. Still you will need to define some basic range from where to pick the random data - i.e. randomly generated characters of a randomly generated length. Do they give you the input on which your program fails?

Comment: well, so after i searched for help on our school forum, the problem is probably in very high numbers. so for example when this program is tested with smthing like 01111111001001010011100000111000101101101110101111101110100111100111000111001011000100001010001100001110010100000001001011000001101 the result is wrong. Shoud i use instead of int, double?

Comment: the problem is probably in function B2
D

Comment: @user1751550 That number takes more than 16 bytes to store, so is too long for any standard numeric type in most platforms. You will need to handle this case somehow. How to do it depends on the exact requirements you have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in function B2D when the binary number is very very high. How to fix it? I cant use double due to pow <<= 1

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with very large numbers, you can either use a bigdecimal library, which isn't probably allowed, or do the calculation by hand with strings as you have learned in elementary school:

1. take the last two digits and add them
2. if the result is 0 or 1, write the digit
3. if the result is greater than 2 (binary 10 or 11) write the least significant digit and carry the overflow to the next place
4. repeat at step 1 until all digits are processed